# display output in Text from module

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a tool to log on a motorolla modem, i get it working and display the output on the python console, this tool have 2 part one part with the gui and the button, label and text frame.
i would like to get the output displayed on the Gui and not to the console.
how can i get that done

here is the files :

---

from Tkinter import *
import motorola

class Application(object):
    def **init**(self):

```
    self.fen = Tk()
    self.fen.title("Motorola tool V 0.1")
    self.fen.geometry("720x480")


    Label(self.fen,
          text = "IP address").grid(row=0)
    #self.entree = MaxLengthEntry(self.fen, maxlength=5)
    self.entree1 = Entry(self.fen)
    self.entree1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label(self.fen,
          text = "Password").grid(row=2)
    #self.entree = MaxLengthEntry(self.fen, maxlength=5)
    self.entree2 = Entry(self.fen)
    self.entree2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    Button(self.fen, text = 'Connect',
           command = self.launch).grid(row = 3, column=2)

    Button(self.fen, text = 'Disconect',
           command = self.exits).grid(row = 3, column=3)
    Button(self.fen, text = 'Quit',
           command = self.fen.quit).grid(row = 5, sticky = E)


    self.output = Text(self.fen)
    self.output.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

    self.fen.mainloop()  



def launch(self):
    self.ip = self.entree1.get()
    self.passw = self.entree2.get()
    print self.ip, self.passw
    if self.passw == "":
        self.entree2.config(bg = 'red')
        self.fen.after(1000, self.empty)

    else:
        self.f = motorola.Motorola(self.ip, self.passw)
        self.f.sh_dsl()

def empty(self):
    self.entree2.configure(bg='white')


def exits(self):
    try:
        self.f.disconnect()
    except AttributeError:
        print "You are not connected"
```

a = Application()

motorola file :

class Motorola(object):
    def **init**(self, ip, passw):

```
    self.ip = ip
    self.passw = passw

    print "connect on the modem"
    self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet(self.ip, '2323' , timeout =5)
    self. tn.read_until("login: ")
    self.tn.write('radadmin\r\n')
    self.tn.read_until("Password:")
    self.tn.write(self.passw+"\r\n")
    data = self.tn.read_until(">")
    print "you are connected"
    print data,
```

def disconnect(self):

```
    self.tn.close()
    print "disconnect from the modem"
```

import telnetlib

---

once i connect on the modem with the button which launch motorola module, how can the data could be displayed on the frame text of the gui module ?

Thank you

Comment: your code is all messed up. Some of it appears as code, some appears as regular text. Please fix the code so people can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is that you have to replace each `print` with some code that adds the string to the GUI.

The trick is that a `Motorola` instance probably doesn't know how to do that. So, what you want to do is pass it something—`self`, or `self.output`, or best of all, a function (closure) that appends to `self.output`. Then the `Motorola` code doesn't have to know anything about Tk (and doesn't have to change if you later write a wx GUI); it just has a function it can call to output a string. For example:

```
def outputter(msg):
    self.output.insert(END, msg + "\n")
self.f = motorola.Motorola(self.ip, self.passw, outputter)
```

Then, inside the Motorola object, just store that parameter and call it everywhere you were using `print`:

```
def __init__(self, ip, passw, outputter):
    self.outputter = outputter
    # ...
    self.outputter("connect on the modem")
```

That almost does it, but how you do handle the magic trailing comma of the `print` function, or even simple things like multiple arguments or printing out numbers? Well, you just need to make `outputter` a little smarter. You could look at the interface of the Python 3 `print` function for inspiration:

```
def outputter(*msgs, **kwargs):
    sep = kwargs.get("sep", " ")
    end = kwargs.get("end", "\n")
    self.output.insert(END, sep.join(msgs) + end)
```

You could go farther—converting non-strings to strings (but not breaking Unicode), etc.—but really, why? If you're trying to get too fancy with `print` or with your `outputter` function, you probably want to let `str.format` do the heavy lifting instead…

Anyway, now, instead of:

```
print data,
```

You do:

```
self.outputter(data, end='')
```

And all of your other `print` statements are trivial.

Comment: Hello Abarnet,Thank you so much for your prompt answer, i was not expected for such a quick answer.

Comment: @neonet: If you understand it, and it works for you, accept it. If there's anything you don't understand, ask first and I'll improve it.

Comment: Hello, i have one more question, this working perfectly, and displaying properly on the text widget, however when i copy and paste the result on a word or a IE form every each line i have like a nous line added... Do you know where it come from ?

Comment: @neonet: What is "a nous line"? You mean there's an extra copy of each line of text? A blank line between each one? Some kind of graphical line-drawing character at the end of each line of text?